# Display Itemcount retrieved using angular js in div

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs

I have retrieved itemcount of a list using http service, but how do I display the count on the UI?

PFB the code:

```
var spApp = angular.module('list-module', []);     
spApp.controller('list-controller', function($scope, $http){  
  $http({  
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('QuestionAnswers')/items?$filter=Title eq "+id+"", //assuming web part is added on same site :)   
        method: "GET",  
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }  
    }).then(function success(data) 
    {
      $scope.answers=data.data.d.results;
      $scope.answersCount=data.data.d.results.length;              
    },
      function error(data) 
    {

    });
});

<div ng-app="list-module">  
    <div ng-controller="list-controller">
      {{answersCount}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad..there was syntax error in my code..it is working perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

try with square brackets:

spApp.controller('list-controller', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
...
}])